# Multiple Pages/Views with Same URL, only fire tag on one of them

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a page that uses a `MultiView` in ASP.NET to hide and show page elements, rather than going to different pages. The same URL is maintained through all of these pages. If I want a tag to fire on, say, the third view in this process, how can I specify this to Google Tag Manager as a rule without having a URL change to base it on? I know there are other options besides URL, but I haven't seen any that would work in this case...

Comment: How do users get to the "third view"? Can you share an image, link, or pseudo HTML code to get an idea of how the page is constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I went with was to add some sort of variable indicating the page I'm on. For example, if my page was called `thirdPage`, then I add to the data layer:

```
dataLayer = [{ 'pageTitle': 'thirdPage' }];
```

and check for this in my tag triggers in Google Tag Manager.